# Resolve Veracode's CWE-73: "External control of file name or path" MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, veracode, secure-coding

I have a function in my application for which I am getting a flaw [CWE-73](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/73.html) from Veracode's scan. This function is used to traverse a specific path and get the content of one file and the list of the files in the folder:

```
private LogFile GetLogFileByName(string logFileName)
{
    string fileContents = string.Empty;
    string path = this.GetBasePath + "/Logs/" + logFileName;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return new LogFile {FileContents = fileContents, LogFileName = logFileName, LogFileNames = GetNames()};
}
```

I looked for possible options to resolve this flaw and one of these was "Pattern Whitelisting", which was applicable for me, so I have rewritten the function in the following way:

```
private LogFile GetLogFileByName(string logFileName)
{
    string fileContents = string.Empty;
    var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^log\.common\.txt(\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2})?$");
    if (regex.IsMatch(logFileName))
    {
      string path = this.GetBasePath + "/Logs/" + logFileName;
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
      {
          using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
          {
              using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
              {
                  fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
              }
          }
      }
    }
    else {
      return new LogFile();
    }

    return new LogFile {FileContents = fileContents, LogFileName = logFileName, LogFileNames = GetNames()};
}
```

Where I use a regex to check if everything is synactically correct. However, the issue still appears. Any ideas, how it can be resolved? I looked into couple posts in SO, but none seems to have any proper explanaition.

Answer (score 0):

Veracode has a knowledge base article that is linked from the flaw viewer that gives some pointers on how to resolve:

https://downloads.veracode.com/securityscan/cwe/v5/net/73.html